# Android programatically disable the cpu usage setting

Tags: android, settings, cpu

Do any one know on how to disable "Show CPU usage" programatically? 
I went through Settings, Secure, System API's, none of them as this name in it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for **"show_processes"** row in [`Settings.Global`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Global.html) table: in order to alter this row your app needs to be a system app, and have `WRITE_SETTINGS` and `WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS` permissions granted.

> Global system settings, containing preferences that always apply identically to all defined users. Applications can read these but are not allowed to write; like the "Secure" settings, these are for preferences that the user must explicitly modify through the system UI or specialized APIs for those values.

With that, [following code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Settings/+/master/src/com/android/settings/DevelopmentSettings.java) should get you through:

```
private void writeCpuUsageOptions(boolean newValue) {
    Settings.Global.putInt(getContentResolver(), "show_processes", newValue ? 1 : 0);
    Intent service = (new Intent()).setClassName("com.android.systemui",
            "com.android.systemui.LoadAverageService");
    if (newValue) {
        startService(service);
    } else {
        stopService(service);
    }
}
```

"Show CPU usage" will be disabled when `newValue` is `false`.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any way for implementing this code on rooted device and it will be on user app?

Comment: Sorry... I am not sure, I don't have any experience with rooted devices. However, I know one can push apk to `/system/app/` folder. Also, you probably could directly write to settings DB using sqlite commands